# Filter array by dict values and keep only unique values

Tags: javascript, arrays

How can I filter this array by the key value "name"

```
arr = [
  {name: "A", val: 1},
  {name: "B", val: 4},
  {name: "C", val: 5},
  {name: "A", val: 2},
  {name: "C", val: 3},
]
```

So that the output looks like this:

```
newArr = [
  {name: "A", val: 1},
  {name: "B", val: 4},
  {name: "C", val: 5},
]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
const arr = [
    { name: 'A', val: 1 },
    { name: 'B', val: 4 },
    { name: 'C', val: 5 },
    { name: 'A', val: 2 },
    { name: 'C', val: 3 },
];

const newArr = arr.filter((value, index, self) => self.findIndex(i => i.name === value.name) === index);

console.log(newArr);
```

Answer (score 0):

In `ES6`, you can make use of `Set`:

```js
var array =[ {name: "A", val: 1}, {name: "B", val: 4}, {name: "C", val: 5}, {name: "A", val: 2}, {name: "C", val: 3},];

var filter = array.filter((s=>({name})=>!s.has(name) && s.add(name))(new Set));

console.log(filter);
```